# text color bootstrap in textarea

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, textarea

```html
 <div class="container">
   <h2>Log</h2>
   <div class="panel-group">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
   <h4 class="panel-title">
     <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseLog">Logger</a>
   </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseLog" class="panel-collapse collapse">
   <div class="panel-body"> 
    <label for="comment">Log:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

am trying to create a WSocket logger and I am trying to Change the Color of the font to green and the Background to gray

doing this in the style Change the Background prefectly:

```
textarea{ 
    background-color:gray !important;
}
```

but if I try to set the text-font Color doing this:

```
textarea{ 
    background-color:gray !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

doenst work...

how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your snippet doesn't really include bootstrap stylesheet, its confusing because using your current snippet(without bootstrap) changing the color DOES work - basically you need to replicate exactly as your project is(including the bootstrap which can be causing the problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a stronger selector on the textarea to override the bootstrap css. For example:

```
#comment {
  color: #fff;
}
```

PS: Obviously you can use !important on that line as well, however it's for extremely rare cases and otherwise considered as (very) bad practice. I'd say that even the usage of #id is a bit of an overkill.

Here is a great guide about selector specificity:
[selector specifities and strengths](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add !important to the "color":

```
textarea {
  background-color:gray !important;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```